# Custom currency-like FungibleAsset in Corda 3.4

Tags: corda

I am implementing custom currency-like issued FungibleAsset in Corda 3.4, the token is a simple enumeration. 
I am stuck with `generateSpend(...)` method.
In `net.corda.finance.contracts.asset.Cash.generateSpend(...)` fun uses `AbstractCashSelection.unconsumedCashStatesForSpending(...)` (in general) which is under the hood calls `VaultService.softLockReserve(...)`.

Questions:
 1. I've never found usage of `VaultService.softLockRelease(...)` for cache flow, is the lock released implicitly?
 2. Shall we implement `AbstractCashSelection`-like `CustomTokenSelection`  and create the copy of cash flow?
 3. Is the current cash flow production ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider using/contributing to the new Tokens SDK 
https://github.com/corda/token-sdk
which will supersede the experimental Finance module (and its current Cash contract)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't messed around with the Token SDK, but from Corda's history it sort of looks like this:

```
override val amount: Amount<Issued<Equity>>
```

In which Equity would look like:

```
    @CordaSerializable
data class Equity(
    val isin: String,
    val defaultFractionDigits: Int = 0
) : TokenizableAssetInfo {
    override val displayTokenSize: BigDecimal
        get() = BigDecimal.ONE.scaleByPowerOfTen(-defaultFractionDigits)

}
```

Again some of the code above could be slightly deprecated, as I haven't messed around with token-sdk, but just a useful reference on how Fungible states are used with Amount, probably a similar thing is going underneath within the SDK.